# How to make sure a class function wont be called until another class function has been called first?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class object that creates some data fields:

```
class DataFields(object):

   _fields_ = ['field_1', 'field_2', 'data_length']

    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data != None:
           self.create_fields(data)

    def create_fields(self, data):
        i = 0
        for field in self._fields_:
            setattr(self, field, data[i])
            i += 1

    def get_datalength(self):
        return self.data_length
```

What is the best way to make sure that the `get_datalength()` function cannot be called unless the `data_length` field has been created (that is, unless the `create_fields()` function has been called once).

I've thought about either using a variable that gets initialized in the `create_fields` and is checked in `get_datalength()` or `try-except` inside the `get_datalength()` function.  What is the most Pythonic (or the best) way?

Comment: The best way is likely to have `create_fields` return a new object with the appropriate methods you want.  Don't try to do everything in one class.

Comment: I think that is exactly what I need to do. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In the above.... is there a reason you need to allow running create_fields after initialization? if you remove the default on data, then it's always guaranteed to be there, because it's always run during init.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. In the complete code the `_fields_` is a two dimensional array that also includes the formatting of the data fields, which I use to unpack the data before I create the fields. Therefore I believe @roippi has the best solution for me.

Comment: that's fine - you can still do that in the `__init__`. the only reason to separate them (and not require creating fields) is if you have some use case where you would create a blank object, keep it around for a while, and then later add data to it.

Comment: That is indeed the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most pythonic way would be to throw an exception:

```
def get_datalength(self):
    try:
        return self.data_length
    except AttributeError:
        raise AttributeError("No length call create_fields first")
```

Simple reason: There is no way to prevent the user to call this function on the object. Either the user would get a `AttributeError` and would not understand what is going on, or you provide an own Error class or at least error message.

BTW:
It is not pythonic creating getter methods(there are no such things as 'private members')
If you need to do smaller operation on the value returning it have a look at the `@property` decorator

```
@property
def datalength(self):
   return do_some_stuff(self.data_length)
```

Comment: btw, for the exception method, you don't need anything at all... if a user tries to access `myobject.field1`, and it hasn't been created, that already will return the value if it exists, and `AttributeError` if it doesn't.

Comment: It's nice to provide a better explanation as to what's wrong, though. You could do this without losing the stack trace with e.g.: `except AttributeError as e: e.args = ("no attribute 'length'; call create_fields first", ); raise`

Comment: I think this is indeed the most pythonic way of doing it. My solution became a mix between this one and something suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

By using `getattr` with default value, you can return `None` or any value if there is no `data_length` attribute yet in instance:

```
def get_datalength(self):
    return getattr(self, 'data_length', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an exception is probably the best way for what you are doing however there are alternatives that may be useful if you will be using this object from an interactive console:

```
def fn2(self):
    print("this is fn2")

class test:
    def fn1(self):
        print("this is fn1")
        self.fn2 = fn2
    def fn2(self):  # omit this if you want fn2 to only exist after fn1 is called
        print("Please call fn1 first")
```

I wouldn't recommend this for every-day use but it can be useful in some cases.  If you omit defining fn2 within the class, then the method fn2 will only be present after fn1 is called.  For easier code maintenance you can do the same thing like this:

```
class test:
    def fn1(self):
        print("this is fn1")
        self.fn2 = self._fn2
    def _fn2(self):
        print("this is fn2")
    def fn2(self):  # omit this if you want fn2 to only exist after fn1 is called
        print("Please call fn1 first")
```

If this is to be used inside a module that will be imported then you should either raise an exception or return a valid value like the other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by having a dictionary, as a class variable, with method names as keys.

```
called['method1'] 
called['method2']
called['method3']
...
```

And setting the key in that method call

```
class SomeClass(obj):
    def method1():
        called['method1'] = 1
    def method2():
        if method1 in called:
            # continue
```